# Strange Behavior with React State and MUI TextFields

Tags: reactjs, uitextfield, setstate

I have a basic set of code .. That I am trying to toggle:

```
{(isLinkPhone) ?
    <Box>
        <TextField
            value={phone}
            label="Phone Number"
            disabled
        />
    </Box>
    :
    <Box>
        <TextField
            defaultValue=''
            label="Link for your button *"
        />
    </Box>
}
```

Basically what I am trying to do is during a toggle of:

```
    const [isLinkPhone, setLinkisPhone] = React.useState(false);
```

I want to display one or the other .. The issue is that I can't set BOTH `value` AND `defaultValue` -- I am having a hard time understanding why React is treating this as the **same** input that cannot have a controlled and uncontrolled value.  What I am trying to do is set the field to "nothing -> enabled/editable" if  `!isLinkPhone` -- Else set it to "`{phone}` -> disabled" -- The issue is that the values "translate" between toggles.

[image]

Is there a better way to go about this?  I am hesitant to create individual components for fear I will spend the time and get the same result.  Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  <Box>
    {isLinkPhone && (
      <TextField value={phone} label="Phone Number" disabled />
    )}

    {!isLinkPhone && (
      <TextField defaultValue="" label="Link for your button *" />
    )}
  </Box>
```

Comment: I also wanted the "display" aspect of the toggle initially set to false .. So I added:  `{isLinkPhone && showLink && (` --  Can you explain why this works, but an `else` doesn't? -- A good answer should always include a descrip[tion as to **why**